# How to wrap image in <a></a> based on condition in asp.net repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say I have a data table with the columns ImageUrl, Text, LinkUrl and Title.

I databind this to a repeater and displays everything without any issue. However, LinkUrl can be empty and then I want the code to be like the one below. If the LinkUrl contains a string/link then I want to wrap the image with a link to the URL. Please ask questions if I need to clarify more.

Example code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptImageGallery">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="slide">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#UrlHelper(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl"))%>'>
    <h2><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %></h2>
    <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")%></p>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = collListItems.GetDataTable().AsEnumerable()
    .Where(a => Convert.ToString(a["Published"]) == "1")
        .CopyToDataTable();

rptImageGallery.DataSource = dt;
rptImageGallery.DataBind();
```

So if the current row contains a link in LikUrl then I want the repeater to present something like this

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptImageGallery">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="slide">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# UrlHelper(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FileLeafRef"))%>' />
    <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LinkUrl")%>' runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %></h2></a>
    <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")%></p>                       
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Edit: something weird with the post. When I go Edit I can see the correct code - slick Save and it doesn't update my code example. Anyway, in the last code part I want a link wrapping the image or image text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="slide">
            <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#GetUrl(Eval("Image"))%>'/>
            <%# WrapTitle(Eval("Title"), Eval("Link"))%>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code behind (I have added complete code so that you can test):

```
Public Class Repeater
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataItem().GetData()
            rpt1.DataSource = dt
            rpt1.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Function WrapTitle(ByVal title As Object, ByVal lnk As Object) As String
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lnk.ToString()) Then
            Return String.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", lnk, title)
        End If
        Return title.ToString()
    End Function

    Protected Function GetUrl(ByVal img As String) As String

        Return Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/") + img
    End Function

End Class

Public Class DataItem
    Private lnks() As String = {"http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.bing.com", "http://www.superuser.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", ""}
    Private titles() As String = {"Google", "Yahoo", "Bing", "superuser", "stackoverflow", "ask.com"}
    Private images() As String = {"nav_logo91.png", "yahoo.png", "bing.png", "superuser.png", "stackoverflow.png", ""}

    Public Function GetData() As DataTable
        Dim dtb As New DataTable
        dtb.Columns.Add("title")
        dtb.Columns.Add("link")
        dtb.Columns.Add("Image")

        For i As Integer = 0 To titles.Length - 1
            dtb.Rows.Add(New Object() {titles(i), lnks(i), images(i)})
        Next

        Return dtb
    End Function

End Class
```

PS:- probably you will not need `GetUrl` function.

Comment: I solved it in another way but this is much more elegant, thanks and yes, I skipped the GetUrl function